# unit-testing component whose props gets value from react navigation component

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

How can I write a unit test for a React Native component which gets its state's value from **React Navigation**, more specific `this.props.navigation.state.params`? This is the component class:

```js
  class RecAreas extends Component{ 
    static navigationOptions =({navigation}) => ({
        title: navigation.state.params.title,

        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
        }, 
          headerTintColor: '#facf33',
    });
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        const params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        this.state={
            key:params.gymId,
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
            }),
        };
        this.mainRef = db.ref("facilities");

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.listenForItem(this.mainRef)
    }
```

I Could not figure out how to pass the nested function as props for the unit test. In this case `this.props.navigation`, `this.props.navigation.state`, `this.props.navigation.state.params` are all objects. How do I mock them for unit test? In the below example I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'gymId' of undefined** which makes sense because `params` is not defined. I need help to resolve this. This is a unit test for the component. Thank you in advance! 
(PS: it would be great to know as well how to mock `dataSource` props as well. One way I thought I could do this is to make a fake `dataSource` data structure  (print out the `dataSource` and look at its structure). Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!)

```js
import React from "react";
import RecAreas from "../../app/screens/RecAreas";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

    describe ("<RecAreas", () => {
        it("renders without crashing", () => {
        const navigationMock = {state: jest.fn()};



        const rendered = renderer.create(<RecAreas navigation= 
                         {navigationMock}/>).toJSON();

        expect(rendered).toBeTruthy();
        expect(rendered).toMatchSnapshot();
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you have mock the props also to generate the tree for snapshot 
like this

```js
import React from "react";
import RecAreas from "../../app/screens/RecAreas";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

describe ("<Test", () => {
    it("renders without crashing", () => {
    const navigationMock = { state: { params: { gymId: "1234" } } };
    const rendered = renderer
      .create(<RecAreas navigation={navigationMock} />)
      .toJSON();
    expect(rendered).toBeTruthy();
    expect(rendered).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
})
```

or you try Enzyme allows for direct manipulation of the props and state of the components